# In Application Insights analytics how to query what percent of users are impacted by specific exception?

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics

I use this query to display exceptions:

```
exceptions
| where application_Version == "xyz"
| summarize count_=count(itemCount), impactedUsers=dcount(user_Id) by problemId, type, method, outerMessage, innermostMessage
| order by impactedUsers
```

How to query what percent of users are impacted by specific exception?

I would check all users by this query:

```
customEvents
| where application_Version == "xyz" 
| summarize dcount(user_Id)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there with what you have, you just need to connect the two:

1. use `let` + `toscalar` to define the results of a query as a number
2. reference that in your query (i used `*1.0` to force it to be a float, otherwise you get 0, and used `round` to get 2 decimals, adjust that however you need)

making your query:

```
let totalUsers = toscalar(customEvents
 | where application_Version == "xyz" 
 | summarize dcount(user_Id));
 exceptions
 | where application_Version == "xyz"
 | summarize count_=count(itemCount), 
      impactedUsers=dcount(user_Id), 
      percent=round(dcount(user_Id)*1.0/totalUsers*100.0,2) 
   by problemId, type, method, outerMessage, innermostMessage
 | order by impactedUsers
```

Comment: Thanks! toscalar is what I was missing